# Import users to local with powershell windows server 2008 r2

Tags: windows, powershell, import, local

I got this script:

```
$Users = Import-Csv C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\userImport\userTest.csv
$Users | % { 

# Setting data
$computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://."
$userGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://./Users,Group"

# Create user itself
$createUser = $computer.Create("User",$_.userid)

# Set password (print1!)
$createUser.SetPassword($_.password)
$createUser.SetInfo()

# Create extra data
$createUser.Description = "Import via powershell"
$createUser.FullName = $_.'full name'
$createUser.SetInfo()

# Set standard flags (Password expire / Password change / Account disabled)
$createUser.UserFlags = 64 + 65536 # ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE + ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD
$createUser.SetInfo()

# Adduser to standard user group ("SERVER02\Users")
$userGroup.Add($createUser.Path)
}
```

But I get the error:
A member could not be added to or removed from the local group because the member does not exist. How Can I possible fix it??

Comment: Any errors in execution earlier than the one you mention?  Sounds like you're having a problem when you go to create the user.

Comment: nope the user is created only that error pops up, is a dot the problem? or doesnt that mather?

Comment: Add the line $createUser | fl * before or instead of $userGroup.Add($createUser.Path), or use the ISE debug feature and a breakpoint.  It will tell you what properties the object has that you can use.  Is path a property and is it populated?  May need to compare that to MSDN to see if it's the right type of argument for the Add method.

Comment: path is populated with: WinNT://XXX.local/./P.Rennings

Comment: Hmm.  Looks good to me, then.  I'll let someone else take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the `.` with the computer name here:

```
$computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://."
```

as

```
$compname = hostname
$computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$compname"
```